# How to reproduce these audible clicking or popping sounds?

Tags: voltage, sound, fault, hacking

My fluorescent lamps (and other devices) are making clicking sounds.

I want to reproduce these clicking or popping sounds or get an idea of how one might produce such sounds in electrical devices or wires. I'm not familiar with electrical engineering, that's why I'm asking this question here.

Here's the sound (you need to turn the volume up, sorry) sample with pictures of this particular device (a lamp in my kitchen):

[audio_sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y5mypEKj4UKvynRN6BPr0i7-pL0g7qMy/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

These sounds *continually appear* in *multiple rooms* from multiple devices. Since they appear day in day out, they're pretty annoying. That's why I'm also interested in the question: If someone (e.g. a neighbour) had access to my network or electrical cables at home, would they be able to manually produce those sounds?

Comment: you posted two unrelated questions ... please delete one and ask in a new post

Comment: are you saying that the lamp is making popping sounds?

Comment: There was no sound from the audio.

Comment: you may have problems with bad connections at power outlets causing arcs ... electrical arcing can sound like random pops ... call an electrician

Comment: @p4rch do you use a hearing aid?

Comment: If various electrical appliances (and possibly even in off state) are making random noise it may be caused by voltage spikes. One can observe similar phenomena during a thunderstorm. The distribution lines do not need to be hit by a lightning but the electromagnetic field may be induced to the power lines acting as an antenna.

Comment: @p4rch:  I don't know what kind of problem other folks are having with your recording.  I can hear a mechanical clock ticking once a second in the background, and every 7 to ten seconds a much louder "tick." I could hear the clock while listening to it on my phone, though I did have to normalize the audio file to hear it on my computer.

Comment: Thank you for your engagement, all! YOU NEED TO CRANK UP THE VOLUME. There is a periodic sound every few seconds made by the device. It appears my recording device is bad at capturing this particular sound. However it is clearly hearable in real life. I also do not use any hearing aids. It is my fault since I could've normalized the recording as @JRE said and did. So still, any ideas how to produce this sound?

Answer (score 1):

I can not really hear something in the audio, but from the pictures i could guess a few sources of sounds:

1. There is the "pling " sound when the fluorescent tube starts (and also potentially when it flickers). That comes from the starter used in these old tubes. In older starters there is a small bi-metal switch, if it is not working correctly it could also maybe "click". To fix this, the starter could be replaced, or even better the lamp could be switched to a modern LED-one. Does it only happen near these kind of fluorescent tube lamps, and only when they are turned on?
2. It could be an old mechanical relay switching. Does it happen when something actually switches, maybe something in another room or even the light in the staircase or something like that?

I would advise to try and pinpoint where the sound is coming from exactly, and when it happens. If it happens in multiple rooms, is there some common device in them? Does it come just out of the wall?

Anyways, i would say it is very unlikely someone (your neighbour) manipulated your netword deliberately to produce such sounds.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. However the tube doesn't flicker and the sound also doesn't appear when the tube starts. Just after a while when it is active. It also happens in rooms, where there are no fluorescent tube lamps. I haven't been able to exactly locate the sound in these cases. It appears they are coming from the walls (I also have recordings of those). These sounds appear mostly when it is quiet and when I am alone. That's why I want to reproduce it in this particular case, to see if I can generalize it to other locations.